# Add Shapes/Controls in a loop VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've to show some PowerPacks.RectangleShape in a PowerPacks.ShapeContainer. A loop in my code add shapes to the container (objshapecontainer.shapes.add(objshape), but at the end of the loop, only the last shape is displayed, in fact objshapecontainer.shapes.count doesn't exceed 1

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the *same* shape (`objshape`) multiple times – this doesn’t work. You need to add *new* shapes each time.

Comment: Yep, I just put the code for creating the shape in a subroutine. Now it works. What's your solution?

Comment: @a438 No need to put it in a subroutine.

Comment: OK. I only need to put the declaration of a new Shape in the loop